# Writing lists in variable form

Tags: list-manipulation

I have three lists $a=\{1,4,7\}, ~b=\{2,5,8\}, ~c=\{3,6,9\}$. I define a result as this,

```
    In[1]:= result = {{12, 10, 9} - {10, 5, 1}, {15, 21, 28} - {14, 17, 
    21}, {30, 22, 17} - {27, 16, 8}}

    Out[1]= {{2, 5, 8}, {1, 4, 7}, {3, 6, 9}}.
```

I want  the output in terms of a, b and c i.e result $=\{b,a,c\}$.

Comment: Your vectors _a_, _b_ and _c_ are not linearly independent, so any answer where the result is not simply a permutation of `{a,b,c}` is inherently ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Use a replacement rule:

```
{{12, 10, 9}  - {10, 5, 1},
 {15, 21, 28} - {14, 17, 21},
 {30, 22, 17} - {27, 16, 8}} /. Thread[{{1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}} -> {"a", "b", "c"}]

(*{b, a, c}*)
```